# Adjust FoV, camera projection parameters for non-camera object?

Tags: rendering, objects, camera

Since the early 2.X days, Blender has allowed non-camera objects, like meshes, empties, and lamps, to be set and used as cameras.

Can the projection parameters be adjusted when doing this?